# Sanitizing function

Tags: php, security

This is a sanitizing function. Is this function secure enough?

```
public function clean( $input, $fordb = true ) {

            global $db;

            //is it an array?
            if( is_array( $input ) ) {

                //yes it is! let's clean each item individually.
                foreach( $input as $key => $value ) {

                    $input[$key] = $this->clean( $value, $fordb );

                }

                return $input;

            }
            else {

                //okay, it isn't, so let's go and tidy it up.
                $input = trim( $input );
                $input = htmlentities( $input, ENT_COMPAT );

                if( $fordb == true and isset( $db ) ) {

                    $input = $db->escape( $input );

                }
                elseif( $fordb == true ) {

                    $input = addslashes( $input );

                }

                return $input;

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the wrong approach to security.  First, a bit of background…

In general, **sanitize** is a bad word to use, as it leads to confusion.  I recommend striking that word from your programming vocabulary (even if the PHP documentation uses it), to be replaced by three specific terms:

1. **Canonicalization** (or "Normalization"): transforming input from multiple representations of the same data into one preferred form.

   For example, if your form accepts a credit card number, then you should strip out all whitespace, because they are not a meaningful part of the data.  Another example would be to [lower-case an e-mail address](//stackoverflow.com/a/9808332/1157100).
2. **Validation:** rejecting input that violates your rules.  Validation failure should cause the user to have to resubmit after fixing the errors.

   For example, if your form accepts a credit card number, then you should reject any submission that does not contain the right number of digits, the correct [leading digits for the accepted card types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_card_number), and a correct [Luhn checksum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm).

   For an e-mail form, your validation rules might require a name to be non-empty, a subject line that is one line of a reasonable length, and a plausible-looking e-mail address.
3. **Escaping:** transforming strings so that one kind of string can be safely embedded inside another kind of string without being misinterpreted.

   Any time you compose a string that will be interpreted by another computer system, be it an e-mail message, HTML page, or SQL query, assume that you are vulnerable to some kind of injection attack. Every single one of these "human-friendly" languages (as opposed to binary formats such as JPEG images) will have delimiters of special significance. Header-splitting, HTML/JavaScript injection, and SQL injection attacks all have the same root cause: careless string concatenation or interpolation.

Canonicalization provides user-friendliness.  Validation enforces your business logic.  **Escaping, not canonicalization or validation, upholds security.**  The term "sanitize" conflates the three mechanisms, leading you do write improperly engineered code.

---

Given that background, I would say that your `clean()` function is somewhere between useless and harmful.  Its main purpose is to escape text "just in case" — there is no clear purpose.

If the input is meant to be stored in a database, then `$db->escape($input)` is the right escaping call.  `addslashes($input)` comes somewhat close to being right if you're using MySQL, but [it's not](//stackoverflow.com/a/3473077/1157100), and it would be far from correct for most other SQL databases.  If the input is destined to be stored in a database, then you certainly don't want to HTML-encode it first.  That's the kind of careless escaping logic that leads to crappy websites that mis-render "&" characters as `&amp;`.  Furthermore, if you store text in the database in mangled form, then it's not properly searchable.

Conversely, if you need to HTML-escape your output, then that `htmlentities()` call has no business being mingled in the same function as your SQL-escaping function.  SQL escaping is for writing strings to a database; HTML escaping is for writing text to the browser.  You would therefore never have a situation where you would want to apply both escaping mechanisms simultaneously to the same string.